# Associate values in excel between different column

Tags: excel

I have two different series of data that look something like this

```
A   B
1 0.998
2 0.9975
3 0.997
4 0.9967
5 0.9962
6 0.9960
.
.
.
```

and

```
C   D
1   240.5
1.3 249.5
1.7 241.45
2   239.0
2.5 124.5
3   125.6
3.4 235.1
3.5 236.4
.
.
.
```

How can I merge the two in excel so that the end results will look like this?

```
C     C    E
1   240.5  0.998
1.3 249.5  0.998
1.7 241.45 0.998
2   239.0  0.9975
2.5 124.5  0.9975
3   125.6  0.997
3.4 235.1  0.997
3.5 236.4  0.997
```

Essentially I need to add, for each integer of the column C, its corresponding value as shown in the series A,B. the whole dataset is 3500 rows long, so I am looking for an automated solution that can help me with that before I resolve to painstakingly paste each value in its position.

Comment: Is column A sorted in ascending order?

Comment: You can query the two tables and merge that query. You can use a vlookup, sumproduct, or sumifs functino to pull in the other values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In column E you can create a formula that uses your first table (A/B) as a LOOKUP table. Truncate the value in Column C as your lookup value.

So in column E, use a formula something like,

```
=LOOKUP(TRUNC(Cx), A1:An, B1:Bn)
```

where `x` is the row number of your C/D/E table, and `n` is the last row in your A/B table.